# Expected Wildcard SSL certificate behavior with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

I have an NSURLConnectionDelegate that's handling SSL challenges, which is working just fine. The question is, why am I seeing the challenge for a wildcard certificate that's otherwise just fine? Note, by just fine I mean the signature is valid and signed by a trusted certificate authority.

Specifically, the certificate is for *.foo.com and the actual host is bar.foo.com -- why doesn't this certificate get automatically accepted?

Edit: After testing a bit more in a one off app, I've realized that if you implement those methods (the challenge handling methods), they're *always* called, not just for "bad" challenges. Is there a way "check" the default handling for a particular challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any better option, we've just decided to implement the certificate validation ourselves using `SecTrustEvaluate(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, &trustEvaluationResult);` From what we've seen, this typically returns the "Unspecified" type result, which indicates that the certificate appears to be valid, but has not yet been added to the user's keychain.